# recoger link desde el cual se le ha llamado a un fichero .PHP

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando un fichero php (que en esencia es HTML, pero con variables), donde tengo variables como `$url`, que contiene el link a otro fichero .PHP. La cuestión es que en este link tengo también información que quiero extraer en el php al que llama.

Para abrir el segundo php, lo hago de esta manera:

```
<a href='<?php echo $url ?>' class="oval"> ACEPTAR </a>
```

Hay alguna manera de recoger la variable `$url`en otro php? (enviándosela al llamar a dicho php, por ejemplo).

Buscando sobre este tema he encontrado la función `ob_get_contents();` pero no sé muy bien cómo aplicarla para este caso ¿Sería válida esta función?

Comment: Prueba con $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Comment: Otra buena idea es colocar el código que tienes en la página origen, y el código de la página destino, así podríamos entender mejor lo que tienes y a dónde quieres llegar.

Comment: La variable `$ulr` es el propio php que se ejecuta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problema

Si comprendo correctamente , lo que quieres hacer es :

- Un enlace en la página php , llamemosle `paginaa.php` , a otra `paginab.php`. Enviandole información de una a otra.

## Formas de enviar información entre páginas PHP.

La forma de enviar información entre páginas son tres :

### La Primera, mediante $_POST y $_GET

En la `páginaa.php` tenemos :

```
<a href='<?php echo $url ?>' class="oval"> ACEPTAR </a>

<a href='http://mipagina.com/paginab.php&a=0?b=2' class="oval"> ACEPTAR </a>
```

Por consiguiente , se puede obtener por la variable global que tiene `php` que es $_GET.

Más información : [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php)

### La segunda , mediante $_SESSION

Esta es otra manera , si en ese caso tienes al usuario logeado. Por el $_SESSION , con el que si haces :

```
$_SESSION["dato"] = "este dato";
```

En la otra página lo podrás obtener sin problema. Siempre que comience por `<?php session_start() ..` , tu página.

Más info : [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php).

### La tercera , mediante Cookies.

Establecemos el tiempo de la cookie y la recuperamos con `$_COOKIE`.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Fuente : [Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp).